# Problem when checking whether std::any variable holds a std::string

Tags: c++, string, types

In c++ you can compare two `type_info` objects.

There is the `std::any` class. It has a member `.type()` that will also return a `type_info` object telling you the type it contains. I can use `typeid(THE_TYPE)` and compare the two.

The following code works:

```
std::any x = 6;

if (x.type() == typeid(int)) {
    cout << "x is int";
}
```

But the following will not work:

```
std::any x = "string literal";

if (x.type() == typeid(std::string)) {
    cout << "x is string";
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I check if a variable is a string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is, `"string literal"` is not of type `std::string`, it's a c-style string, i.e. a `const char[15]` itself. And `std::any` takes it as `const char*`. So if you change the condition as follows you'll get `"x is string"` printed out.

```
if (x.type() == typeid(const char*))
```

To solve the issue you can pass an `std::string` to `std::any` explicitly.

```
std::any x = std::string("string literal");
```

Or use [literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s).

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
std::any x = "string literal"s;
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::any x = “string literal”;` does not store a `std:: string`. It stores a `char const [15]`.

I think the right way of fixing it, is by ensuring you store std::string. Either by writing: `std::any x = std::string{ “string literal”};`  or by writing `std::any x = “string literal”s;`  (this last one needs a using for the literals `using namespace std::string_literals;`)

Personally, I would also consider `std::string_view` to put in the any, as it doesn't allocate memory for the string. However it might complicate the usage.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the statement `std::any x = “string literal”;` treats "string literal" as a character constant. So the type of x would be `const char*`.
To make the code work as you want, you can change that as :

```
std::any x = std::string(“string literal”);

if (x.type() == typeid(std::string)) {
 cout << “x is string”;
}
```

This may solve your problem, Thanks